# Does snap require particular certificates to be installed?

Tags: 16.04, software-installation, snap, certificates

Messing around on my self-rolled distro, closely based on Ubuntu 16.04, I tried building and installing the hello-world snap.

It seemed to build fine with snapcraft but `sudo snap install hello_2.10_amd64.snap` failed with `error: cannot find signatures with metadata for snap "hello_2.10_amd64.snap"`.

Adding `--devmode` then produced:

`error: cannot install snap file: Get https://search.apps.ubuntu.com/api/v1/snaps/details/core?channel=stable&fields=anon_download_url%2Carchitecture%2Cchannel%2Cdownload_sha3_384%2Csummary%2Cdescription%2Cdeltas%2Cbinary_filesize%2Cdownload_url%2Cepoch%2Cicon_url%2Clast_updated%2Cpackage_name%2Cprices%2Cpublisher%2Cratings_average%2Crevision%2Cscreenshot_urls%2Csnap_id%2Csupport_url%2Ctitle%2Ccontent%2Cversion%2Corigin%2Cdeveloper_id%2Cprivate%2Cconfinement: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority`

I assume it's trying to check something online, perhaps because I don't have the default Ubuntu CA certificates installed?

Update: The version of snap is 2.22.6.

Comment: Could you add the version of snap , `snap --version`

Comment: Ah, left for the weekend now. It's whatever is default in 16.04 if that helps, but I'll check on Monday.

Comment: Possible cause, original `hello` from snap repo was installed , check `snap list`. if it is not installed then may be `snap` checks with repo for signature. Either way, try rename your local snap to something unique and rebuild it.

Comment: Nothing installed and renaming still gives the same error. I thought installing the ca-certificates package might help but unfortunately not.

Comment: My  `snap`   is `2.23.6` , `snapcraft` is `2.28` . Could you update yours? Also if possible to share that built snap package . I want try it in my machine . to confirm if the issue with `snap` or `snapcraft`

Comment: I pinned the snapd package to yakkety and updated it to get 2.24.1 but it gives the same error again. Built snap file here: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B03d6VGmwCSyeWtMU0hEQllXNEY1dmwxNmstZkNaQk04VmVj

Comment: I don't get same error, so it is something related to `snap` and  not the package or `snapcraft`. Also found [a bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/snappy/+bug/1620755) about same issue .  Are you using a proxy?

Comment: No, no proxy - I kept stumbling across those reports as well but this is just a direct internet connection. There must be something funky about my cert setup. Even so, it's a shame you have to be online to install snaps. Pulling the network connection gives "server misbehaving"...

Answer (score 2):

If you are installing a snap you've built locally you need to add the `--dangerous`, so in your case:

`sudo snap install hello_2.10_amd64.snap --dangerous`

Comment: Thanks but unfortunately that gives me the same error as `--devmode`.